# Problema en Consulta Laravel

Tags: select, sql

En mi programa realizo esta consulta:

```
$polizas = DB::table('polizas')
        ->join('aseguradoras', 'aseguradora_id', '=', 'aseguradoras.id')
        ->join('contratos','contrato_id','=','contratos.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('Codigo_Poliza',
                 'Valor_Poliza',
                 'Tipo_Poliza',
                 'Vigencia_Desde',
                 'Plazo',
                 'adddate(Vigencia_Desde, Plazo) as Vigecia_Hasta',
                 'DATEDIFF(adddate(Vigencia_Desde, Plazo), CURDATE()) as Dias_Restantes',
                 'aseguradora_id','aseguradoras.Razon_Social as Razon_Social','contrato_id',
                 'contratos.Codigo_Contrato as Codigo_Contrato','Estado','Renovacion','Fecha_Cierre',
                 'polizas.created_at'))
        ->where('Tipo_Poliza', '=','Fiel Cumplimiento')
        ->where('Estado', '=','1')
        ->havingRaw('Dias_Restantes <= ? and Dias_Restantes >= ?',[15,0])
        ->get();
```

Y me devuelve el siguiente error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'Dias_Restantes' in 'having clause' (SQL: select Codigo_Poliza from
> `polizas` inner join `aseguradoras` on `aseguradora_id` =
> `aseguradoras`.`id` inner join `contratos` on `contrato_id` =
> `contratos`.`id` where `Tipo_Poliza` = Fiel Cumplimiento and `Estado`
> = 1 having Dias_Restantes <= 15 and Dias_Restantes >= 0)

Answer (score 0):

La clausula `HAVING` se utiliza como condicional de un `GROUP BY`, cosa que no veo que tengas. Cual es tu motivación para meter esa condición en el having? Porque no podes simplemente hacer:

```
 ->where('Dias_Restantes <= ? and Dias_Restantes >= ?',[15,0])
```

Lo que te esta diciendo es que no conoce el nombre de la columna Dias_Restantes en la cláusula Having, lo cual hace mucho sentido porque vos no hiciste un `GROUP BY`. Estos van siempre de la mano y por eso no logra encontrar el nombre de la columna. Si agruparas por *Dias_Restantes* podrias utilizar el codigo como lo tienes pero evidentemente creo que el resultado no sería el que esperás.

> Edición sumando respuesta de comentario

Tu definicion de **Dias_Restantes** está en el `SELECT` y por lo tanto solo se usa como "nombre" de columna o para darle un nombre a los datos representados por esa columna. Pero dicho nombre no tiene valor fuera del `SELECT`. Para entender mejor esto deberias buscar informacion de que se ejecuta primero en una query, a lo que voy el resultado de todo el procesamiento (joins, where, having ....) luego se procesa para renderizar las columnas especificadas en el select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En la parte de la derecha de la imagen es como escribis tu query SQL, en la parte de la izquierda es el orden que sigue el DBMS para leer y procesar la query.

Si reemplazas tu **Dias_Restantes** por su definicion `DATEDIFF(adddate(Vigencia_Desde, Plazo), CURDATE())` debería de funcionarte porque tal como dice el error **Dias_Restantes** no es parte de la tabla.

Comment: Es mas una pregunta de la sintaxis SQL que de laravel

Comment: te comento que seguí tu recomendación y tengo el mismo resultado, no encuentra el campo alias Dias_Restantes en la consulta.

Comment: Bien, me acabo de percatar de algo, tu definicion de `Dias_Restantes` está en el `SELECT` y por lo tanto solo se usa como "nombre" de columna o para darle un nombre a los datos representados por esa columan. Pero dicho nombre no tiene valor fuera del `SELECT`. Para entender mejor esto deberias buscar informacion de que se ejecuta primero en una *query*, a lo que voy el resultado de todo el procesamiento (joins, where, having ....) luego se procesa para renderizar las columnas especificadas en el select

Comment: Si reemplazas tu **Dias_Restantes** por su definicion `DATEDIFF(adddate(Vigencia_Desde, Plazo), CURDATE())` debería de funcionarte porque tal como dice el error **Dias_Restantes** no es parte de la tabla